# $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTop() doesn't allow me to scroll up manually after it scrolls down my list

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a problem with using $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTop()
I need to scroll down my book list to appropriate book after going out from the reader. I desided to use $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTop() for this purpose.
It works, but I cannot scroll up my list manually after that.

Maybe someone knows why it happens.

Here is my code:

```
$timeout(function(){
            var BooksListScroll = $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('BooksListScroll');
            $location.hash("main" + $rootScope.currentBookCode);
            BooksListScroll.scrollTop(true);                
        }, 500);
```

Comment: Any update on this one?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using android platform to do a test, remove the 'true' value on the function. Ex:

```
BooksListScroll.scrollTop(true);
```

to

```
BooksListScroll.scrollTop();
```

Do a try.. IOS is working fine with the scroll animation but on android the scroll animation make the view freeze! Weird! :(

UPDATE (SOLUTION):

Okay I found the solution.. It seem we need to set 'jsScrolling: true' instead of by default is 'jsScrolling: false' for android.

Please modified/edit this on 'ionic-angular.js'

Hope it help others :)